# Is there a way to draw different icons for draw points in Mapbox GL js?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker, mapbox-gl-draw

In Mapbox GL js, is there a way to draw different draw_point icons in same map. I'm going to add drawing tools and there are different icons. After selecting one icon, the user can be able to draw the map.
Ex: user can select tree icon and place that icon on the map. Then the user can select a house icon and put a house on the map.

Answer (score 0):

```
const mapBoxDrawOptions = {
  displayControlsDefault: false,
  controls: {},
  styles: [
    {
      id: 'gl-draw-point',
      type: 'symbol',
      filter: ['all', ['==', '$type', 'Point'], ['!=', 'mode', 'static']],
      layout: {
        'icon-image': 'custom-icon',
        'icon-size': 1,
        'icon-anchor': 'bottom',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Add 'mapBoxDrawOptions' to:

```
const draw = new MapboxDraw(mapBoxDrawOptions);
```

And on 'draw.create', Add this part:

```
map.on('draw.create', () => {
    if (draw.getMode() === 'draw_point') {
      map.loadImage('Your_Icon_Is_Here', (error, image) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        image && map.addImage('custom-icon', image);
      });
    }
  });
```